# Consuming Odata from Dynamics NAV with ASP

Tags: visual-studio-2012, odata, dynamics-nav

I have VS 2012 professional and Dynamics NAV 2016
and want to explore possibilities with consuming ODATA

I click on Add Service Reference and then I type in the ODATA URL
Then I click on Go and I see NAV and inside I see Company and the different web services I created in Dynamics NAV 2016.
In my case I have only 1 published web service (page 21 customercard)
When I click on OK I get the following Error :

[image: error message]

I do not have any idea what this is meaning and how I can go on !
Any help would be nice !

EDIT :
Error message in englishtranslated as good as I can :
The Custom Tool 'DataServicesCoreClientGenerator' failed. Data service client code generation failed : Schema specified is not valid. Errors: Error 0005 : The attribute 'Name' is not valid according to his data type 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/05/edm:TSimpleIdentifier' - Failure of the constraint pattern

Comment: What does the error says?

Comment: Have you tried creating a much simpler page, based on the customer table?  From my experience application integrators prefer to work with only the fields that they are interested in, and not the complete customer details.

Comment: I added translation of the error message

Comment: I understand your proposition but I would like to know why this error happens

Answer (score 1):

I found a video explaining how to add the reference which is a web service reference :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qQG3r5QM7pQ
So my exploration can go on ... :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It was being caused by one of the pages (42) which had been published under web services. After unchecking the published check box, adding the o Data service worked fine. Just get the specific object causing the error and you will be okay